# Using Python to Search for a variable number of strings in stdout feed and exit elegantly

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, configuration-files

I have some code below, which I admit is very repetitive in terms of tasks, I am looking for a cleaner way to exit a while loop based on strings found in a dynamic stdout feed.

I have a config file which outlines various test scenarios and highlights the string sequences to search for . Sometimes a test will require only two strings to be found, other times as much as four strings will need to be found, hence the **try and except** blocks below. If the string can't be found in the config file for that particular test scenario it will set the 'stringfound**n**' to **None**.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#while loop runs from here looking through stdout from log file:
while not stdout_queue.empty():
    line = stdout_queue.get()

    #There will always be one string to look for
    string1 = config.get(TestType, 'STRING1')
    matchString1 = re.search(string1, line)

    # See if String 2 is in Config file for testtype - else set to None
    try:
        string2 = config.get(TestType, 'STRING2')
        matchString2 = re.search(string2, line)
    except:
        stringFound2 = None

    # See if String 3 is in Config file for testtype - else set to None
    try:
        string3 = config.get(TestType, 'STRING3')
        matchString3 = re.search(string3, line)
    except:
        stringFound3 = None
        pass

    # See if String 3 is in Config file for testtype - else set to None 
    try:
        string4 = config.get(TestType, 'STRING4')
        matchString4 = re.search(string4, line)
    except:
        stringFound4 = None
        pass


    if matchString1 and not stringFound1:
        stringFound1 = 1

    if matchString2 and not stringFound2:
        stringFound2 = 1

    if matchString3 and not stringFound3:
        stringFound1 = 1

    if matchString4 and not stringFound4:
        stringFound4 = 1



    if ((stringFound2 and stringFound3 and stringFound4) is None) and stringFound1:
        # do stuff here in cases where only ONE string is entered into Config file testtype
        return

    if ((stringFound3 and stringFound4) is None) and (stringFound1 and stringFound2):
        # do stuff here in cases where only TWO strings are entered into Config file testtype                
        return

    if stringFound4 is None and (stringFound1 and stringFound2 and stringFound3):
        # do stuff here in cases where only THREE strings are entered into Config file testtype
        return

    if stringFound1 and stringFound2 and stringFound3 and stringFound4:
        # do stuff here in cases where only THREE strings are entered into Config file testtype
        return
```

Aside for the possibility of tidying up the loop, I think my problem lies with the **('is None) and (stringFound)** if statements at the end.  Any ideas on how to streamline, or better exit this loop?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `config` and `TestType`? The very least you could do to simplify the code would be to use lists for `string`, `matchString` and `stringFound` instead of numbered variables. Is `stringFound` really necessary, what does the `config.get()` return if the string is not found?

Answer (score 0):

The `re.search` function already returns None if the string is not matched so there is no need for 2 variables per string to be matched:

```
try:
    string2 = config.get(TestType, 'STRING2')
    matchString2 = re.search(string2, line)
except:
    #stringFound2 = None
    matchString2 = None
```

`None` in Python is not the same as `False`, but it is evaluated as such. Take the example:

```
a = None
b = True
c = None
print (a and  b)
print (a or  b)
print None == False
print not None
d = a and  b
if not d: print 'Trueish'
```

So you can remove the first block of `if` statements and replace the last block with something like:

```
if matchString1 and not (matchString2 or matchString3 or matchString4 ):
    # if any of matchString2, 3 or 4 is entered the condition fails
    # do stuff here in cases where only ONE string is entered into Config file testtype
    return
```

You may need to adjust the condition(s) but my point of view is there.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```py
string_count = 4
while not stdout_queue.empty():
    line = stdout_queue.get()

    strings = []
    matches = []
    for i in range(string_count):
        string = None
        match = None
        try:
            string = config.get(TestType, 'STRING{}'.format(i + 1))
            match = re.search(string, line)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        strings.append(string)
        matches.append(match)
    valid_strings = tuple(map(bool, strings))
    valid_matches = tuple(map(bool, strings))
    found = valid_strings and valid_matches
    found_count = sum(found)

    # If you want to check that specific strings were found
    if found == (True, False, False, False):
        # Do something
        pass
    # If you want to do something based on the number of found strings
    if found_count == 2:
        pass
```